Python Pants Error : "remote install is not supported on this platform!"
I used pants run command for my python application. I've tried both with 2.17.0 version and 2.21.0a1. I googled the "not supported" error but didn't come up with any results. Is it related to having macbook m2 pro? maybe it works with M1 and linux but not on M2?
commands like version, help they all seem fine but I can't run my apps.
saygin@mbpro trial-project % pants run main.py                             
[INFO  scie_pants] Found Pants build root at Some("/Users/saygin/dev")
[INFO  scie_pants] The required Pants version is Some("2.21.0a1")
remote install is not supported on this platform!
saygin@mbpro trial-project %


"I googled the "not supported" error but didn't come up with any results." Have you tried the documentation directly, or the issue tracker?

I checked documentation of course. But whatever software tool you check nobody specifically says m2, usually there is just apple m1 support. They have it too.
I haven’t opened an issue yet I will do that as well

When you say pants version seems fine, does that mean that it prints 2.21.0a1 or similar? If so, that means that Pants is successfully installed and running... That would suggest that potentially the exception comes from whatever code is in main.py.
If you replace main.py's contents with print("Hello world!"), does pants run main.py print Hello world!? If so, it'll likely be one of the dependencies you're using, which you'll need to track down yourself.

I suspected the same and just added print to the first line within main.py but it didn't print anything either maybe I run into pants conclusion too fast.
thanks once more, indeed it was the dependencies, the one you found.

I think this may be an issue with one of the dependencies (viztracer) being used by the code being executed by pants run main.py, not Pants itself.
The description of pants version working (presumably, printing whatever is written in pants.toml's [GLOBAL].pants_version setting) implies that Pants is installed and running successfully.
Doing a GitHub code search finds this chunk of code in the viztracer package:
    def install(self) -> None:
        if (sys.platform == "win32"
                or (sys.platform == "darwin" and "arm" in platform.processor())):
            print("remote install is not supported on this platform!")
            sys.exit(1)

Thus, on arm macOS, this package apparently needs to be used in a different way!

yes, that was the issue
it's strange that the error log didn't show up anywhere, I'll keep in mind searching github code search if anything similar comes up.
thanks @huon

Sounds like something worth reporting on either or both issue trackers. Perhaps the viztracer restriction is artificial. Perhaps the Pants team is unaware of the restriction.

@KarlKnechtel I'm a Pants maintainer, and strongly suspect this is completely unrelated to Pants, which is just a venv-creator and command-runner in this case: I would imagine executing the same code on the same platform outside Pants will fail in the same way.

Ah, I misunderstood. I thought viztracer was a dependency of Pants itself.
